# Handlebars triple stache inside of a double stache

Tags: template-engine, handlebars.js, handlebarshelper

I have registered a handlebars helper by the name of "t" that will translate a string.  I have a Handlebars template which uses the value of a variable that will be a word:

```
{{{word}}}
```

I would like to translate the value of that variable using my helper, but cannot do

```
{{t "{{{word}}}" }}   or   {{t {{{word}}} }}
```

I am inexperienced with Handlebars and am wondering - What is the simplest way to achieve this?

Comment: You cannot enclose moustache expressions inside of other moustache expressions.

Answer (score 1):

### {{t word}}

Simply pass the reference into your helper without brackets.

You only need brackets for outputting the value of the reference to the page:

> Handlebars HTML-escapes values returned by a {{expression}}. If you
>   don't want Handlebars to escape a value, use the "triple-stash", {{{.

**UPDATE:**

If you need to perform some kind of operation (such as escaping HTML) on the value of `word`, you can make a second helper and pass that into your first helper using `(` parentheses `)`:

`{{t (myOtherHelper word)}}`